# How can I give css to angular's custom directive from css file?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I want to create a custom button directive in angular. I want to know, how can I give css to that directive using css file.How can i link it to css file.

I tried keeping directive and  css file in one section. But it didn't work.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.